# Trying to understand if fail2ban is working on Debian 10 VPS

Tags: fail2ban

I have a Debian 10 server running on a VPS.
The only software I installed is:  tinyproxy (http proxy)  and  fail2ban

I have included the results of port scan using nmap

I have included my specific settings in the fail2ban jail.local file.

I have included my specific settings in the fail2ban fail2ban.local file.

I have included below a sample of entries from auth log.

I have included below a sample of entries from fail2ban log.

I have included my results from sample scan of IpTables.

I do not understand if fail2ban is working,
i.e. causing IPs to be blocked based upon entries in the IP Tables that fail2ban has made.

As example:

== auth.log shows attempted entry by 192.241.141.43, almost every minute

== fail2ban.log shows 192.241.141.43 is banned

== Iptables shows 192.241.141.43 is banned

I thought that based upon the IP being blocked, that the malicious user would NOT be able to attempt a login.
Yet it seems that these users are indeed being able to attempt logins.

MY QUESTIONS, Please:

1. Does it appear that fail2ban is working?
2. Why are malicious users allowed to even attempt login if they are banned?

Many thanks !

## ===
=== Results from nmap scan

```
# Nmap 7.80 scan initiated Sat Jan 27 15:25:04 2024 as: nmap -sS -oG out.txt 

107.174.156.124

Host: 107.174.156.124 (107-174-156-124-host.colocrossing.com)   
Status: 
Up
Host: 107.174.156.124 (107-174-156-124-host.colocrossing.com)   
Ports: 
139/filtered/tcp//netbios-ssn///, 
445/filtered/tcp//microsoft-ds///, 
8888/open/tcp//sun-answerbook///    
Ignored State: closed (997)

# Nmap done at Sat Jan 27 15:25:06 2024 
-- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.20 seconds
```

## ===
=== Here are my entries in jail.local

```
#
# JAILS
#

#
# SSH servers
#

[sshd]

# To use more aggressive sshd modes set filter parameter "mode" in jail.local:
# normal (default), ddos, extra or aggressive (combines all).
# See "tests/files/logs/sshd" or "filter.d/sshd.conf" for usage example and details.
#mode   = normal
enabled = true
mode = aggressive
port = 63xxx
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
bantime = 2000000
findtime = 7200
maxretry = 2
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
action = iptables-multiport[name=sshd, port="ssh", protocol=tcp]
```

## ===
=== Here are my entries in fail2ban.local

```
# Options: dbpurgeage
# Notes.: Sets age at which bans should be purged from the database
# Values: [ SECONDS ] Default: 86400 (24hours)
dbpurgeage = 2100000
```

## ===
=== Here is sample Auth log

As example, there are several attempts by  192.241.141.43
And this is repeated almost every minute !

```
Jan 27 15:54:55 racknerd-64d010 sshd[2232]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.241.141.43  user=root
Jan 27 15:54:57 racknerd-64d010 sshd[2232]: Failed password for root from 192.241.141.43 port 54798 ssh2
Jan 27 15:54:57 racknerd-64d010 sshd[2232]: Received disconnect from 192.241.141.43 port 54798:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 27 15:54:57 racknerd-64d010 sshd[2232]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 192.241.141.43 port 54798 [preauth]
```

## ===
=== Here is  sample of fail2ban

As example, fail2ban says 192.241.141.43 is banned

```
2024-01-27 15:55:50,928 fail2ban.actions        [29992]: WARNING [sshd] 82.102.12.130 already banned
2024-01-27 15:55:50,929 fail2ban.actions        [29992]: WARNING [sshd] 192.241.141.43 already banned
2024-01-27 15:55:50,929 fail2ban.actions        [29992]: WARNING [sshd] 159.75.161.40 already banned
```

## ===
=== Results from Iptables scan

IP 192.241.141.43 is banned

```
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       61.231.64.170        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       192.241.141.43       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       104.250.34.177       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: Do you have sshd running on a non-standard port? Have you checked that iptables rules apply to the same port that your sshd running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's working according to your log file.

`/var/log/fail2ban.log`

Fail2ban also has it's own tool to check the status with
`fail2ban-client status sshd`

On my machine where it's working it looks like this

```
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 3
|  |- Total failed:     192
|  `- File list:        /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 41
   |- Total banned:     41
   `- Banned IP list:   139.199.207.102 1
57.230.232.203 167.71.61.117 178.128.244.
113 185.36.81.42 221.226.2.122 222.186.16
.186 222.186.16.198 45.155.91.99 52.91.19
4.171 78.68.68.246 212.70.149.150 141.98.
11.90 85.209.11.27 138.68.111.27 183.221.
243.20 218.92.0.56 218.92.0.113 218.92.0.
112 218.92.0.22 218.92.0.25 218.92.0.76 2
18.92.0.107 85.209.11.254 218.92.0.34 218
.92.0.118 180.101.88.197 218.92.0.29 218.
92.0.24 218.92.0.27 141.98.11.11 1.117.16
8.14 180.101.88.196 218.92.0.31 88.182.25
1.194 88.214.25.16 35.243.208.234 124.222
.51.236 118.121.200.110 14.103.25.183 121
.164.71.235
```

Comment: Thank you Turdie for comment. What confuses me the most is that any of these "attacking" IPs keep coming back, AND the kernel seems to try to authenticate them as evidenced by the pam_unix(sshd:auth) entries. Why doesn't the kernel just disconnect if their IP is in the ban list in Iptables??

Comment: For the coming back ips you have the recidive jail, which monitors the fail2ban log. Byde

Comment: Please, what is "recidive jail"?

Comment: See here https://bpaulino.com/entries/hardening-your-server-security-with-fail2ban. I added it also my answer

Comment: Even if fail2ban shows an IP as banned, it doesn't mean that iptables filters were applied correctly. With bantime = 2000000 you shouldn't see the same IP every minute and "already banned" warnings.